# How to set the size of the textView Based on the screen size of the device

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I m designing an TextView for my project, I m facing issue of font size for various devices.
I there any option to set the font size based on the device width?
kindly help me regarding this

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Starts"
   android:minEms="6" android:gravity="end"
   style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
   android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: post your xml code here

Comment: Actually you can make it based on screen density using "sp" as font unit. You can think about "sp" as "dp". So just specify textSize property to be in "sp" (e.g. "android:textSize="16sp") and everything should be alright.

Comment: I m doing it using dp

Comment: @NikhilSharma Nothing much difference in xml it is same as normal decleration

Comment: you should post your xml

Comment: `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Starts"
                            android:minEms="6"
                            android:gravity="end"
                            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>`

Comment: I Mean you edit your post and post full xml file i dont know your using textView horizontal or vertical orientation

Answer (score 0):

add below dependency in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
```

and use below example

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Intuit"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_40sdp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in TextView :

```
style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
```

Comment: Okay like separate dimension for diff. devices

Comment: Yes. you can give textview size. i think its better to go dimens

Answer (score 0):

Android O (API 26) brings [Autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html), which can be used for this purpose. Using the Support Library 26, you can use this feature down to API 14.